# Progressbar not hitting 100% when expected

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker, stopwatch

I am using a background thread to run a stopwatch which I am using on a label and to increment a progressbar. The timer seems to be keeping time accurately but the progress bar isn't hitting 100% when I expect it to.

I am trying to use both to time 35 seconds and it hits 100% at nearly 36s, can anyone tell me why?

The Maximum value of the progress bar is set to 350, value is set to 0.

```
private int currentScore = 0;

Stopwatch swTimer = new Stopwatch();

private void backgroundWorkerTimer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan elapsedTime = swTimer.Elapsed;
    labelTime.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1:%f}", elapsedTime.Seconds, elapsedTime);
    progressBarTimer.Increment(1);
}

private void backgroundWorkerTimer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        backgroundWorkerTimer.ReportProgress(0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Not clear, do you want the progressbar  full after 35 secs? And you get it full after how many seconds?

Comment: Yes, I want it full after 35s and it is nearly 36 when it hits 100%.

Comment: I think that this could be expected. Windows is not a real-time OS and every time you call ReportProgress there is a thread switch. A performance intensive operation, so some milliseconds are lost and you have the observed behavior. Not an expert in this field so I could be proven wrong

Comment: Not quite Steve. Thread.Sleep is most likely your problem. That method should stop your thread running for at least 1000ms but it can be unbounded how long execution is deferred. For regularly invoking a method you should use a timer.

Comment: The labelTime label is updating accurately though, and that is being called in the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have dried up so I will close it. I ended up making the progressBar max 345 and it seems to hit the end at about 35s, I am only using it for a visual representation of time left anyway.

Would be interested to know why 350 as a maximum isn't accurate though when labelTime is keeping up.